# Identify whether a field is of type group: string (character) types

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there something in information schema, or some other method, that will tell me if a field is textual or not. I.e. Without checking DATA_TYPE against each possible type, i want to identify if that field belongs to the group: string (character) types.

This is so that i can create an object of the appropriate type in my c++ code.

Comment: You can check for CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH being NOT NULL.  However, I think your code will be clearer if you use an "IN" statement with the types you are looking for.

Comment: unfortunately CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH return not null for other types. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @idgorman . . . Try COLLATION_NAME.  MySQL documentation is vague, but SQL Server documents this as only being used for character and text types.  (And it documents CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as being used for image and binary types as well.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff this looks promising. i'll exclude enums manually (although they are valid in this group). Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mark the question as answered GordonLinoff said: Try COLLATION_NAME. MySQL documentation is vague, but SQL Server documents this as only being used for character and text types. (And it documents CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as being used for image and binary types as well.)